# How to execute an action before start()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am developing a spark streaming job(using structured streaming not using DStreams). I get a message from kafka and that will contain many fields with comma separated value out of which the first column will be a filename. Now based on that filename i will have to read the file from HDFS and create a dataframe and operate further on the same. This seems to be simple, but spark is not allowing me to run any actions before the start is called. Spark Documentation also quotes the same.

> In addition, there are some Dataset methods that will not work on
>   streaming Datasets. They are actions that will immediately run queries
>   and return results, which does not make sense on a streaming Dataset.

Below is what i have tried.

```
object StructuredStreamingExample {
  case class filenameonly(value:String)
  def main(args:Array[String])
  {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    spark.sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5")

    import spark.implicits._
    val lines = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "strtest")
      .load()
   val values=lines.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String]
   val filename = values.map(x => x.split(",")(0)).toDF().select($"value")
   //Here how do i convert the filename which is a Dataframe to string and apply that to spark.readtextfile(filename)
   datareadfromhdfs
  .writeStream
  .trigger(ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("console")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Now in the above code after i get the filename which is a Dataframe how do i convert that to a String so that i can do spark.readtextfile(filename) to read the file in HDFS.

Comment: I think the title might be misleading given the discussion we had.

Comment: Ya true, at the start i was expecting for a solution using Streaming Dataframe but after our discussion this doesn't seems to be a use case for streaming itself. So let the topic be the same and i will wait for an answer related to streaming dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best use for spark streaming but in a case like this, I would call filename.foreachRDD and read hdfs files from in there and do whatever you need after.
(Keep in mind that when running inside a foreachRDD, you cannot use global spark session but need to getOrCreate it from the builder like that: `val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(myCurrentForeachRDD.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()`)

You seems to rely on a stream to tell you where to look and load files..  Have you tried simply using a file stream on that folder and let spark monitor and read new files automatically for you?

Comment: Thanks for the attention. Correct me if i am wrong when i follow approach one. Say i have a kafka topic with 15 partitions, and the message from the producer end is sent to the topic in a round robin fashion. So if a producer sends 30 messages then each partition will have 2 messages. Now from spark point of view the parallelism will be 1:1(kafka partition:spark core). In that case if i use a foreachRDD(which executes in the driver) and get all the values from a particular topic the whole 30 messages will be processed by a single spark core since i am not looping till foreachPartition here.

Comment: The problem in using second approach is that, as i mentioned earlier the directory name will be dynamic from the kafka message, and hence i cannot look for a particular directory.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how kafka connector works so I can't tell about batching there..  What I can tell is when I use Kinesis with multiple shards, I receive RDD with multiple partitions. Since it is an RDD, I can still repartition it to match the degree of parallelism i need.

Comment: But the problem is usually we would usually want the source to decide the parallelism because they know the data well than the spark.

Comment: Sure but in general with spark, there is a range of values where throughput is maximized.. From my experience, too many partitions hinder performances as well.  So I generally seek to have the number of partitions 2-3 times the number of cores.

Comment: Agree. That was a ideal configuration(partition:core) for me as well. I will wait for another solution using the approach which i was trying if not i will go with approach 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is sure not the best use case to use spark structured streaming. If you understand the spark structured streaming correctly all the data transformations/aggregations should happen on the query that generates result table. However you can still implement some workarounds where you can write the code to read data from HDFS in (falt)mapWithGroupState. But, again it is not advisable to do so.